# How do I back up a remote SVN repository

Tags: svn, backup

I am currently moving my SVN server from my home server to my remote server so I can access it more easily from other locations.
My remote server is not backed up so I want to regularly back it up to my home server.

Remote server is Windows 2003 server. Home server is Windows Home Server.

What is the best way to do this? can I get my home server to get a dump of the remote server every night? Bandwidth isn't a huge consideration but if I could just copy any new checkins to an SVN server on my home server that would be fine.

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Thanks for all your speedy replies. I think SVNSync is going to do exactly what I want. 
Pekka - you're right if I had thought about it Serverfault would probably have been a better to ask this. I get such good quick answers on here that I didn't consider the other sites.
Thanks again.

Comment: Asca'! Cazzo! usa questo comando! (scherzo) :-)

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Just use the [svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.svnsync.html) command.

First, create a fresh repository on your home machine.

```
svnadmin create c:\backuprepo
```

Or on Unix:

```
svnadmin create ./backuprepo
```

Next, create a file named pre-revprop-change.bat:

```
echo exit 0 > c:\backuprepo\hooks\pre-revprop-change.bat
```

Or on Unix:

```
echo -ne '#!/bin/sh\nexit 0' > ./backuprepo/hooks/pre-revprop-change
chmod ugo+x ./backuprepo/hooks/pre-revprop-change
```

then, initialize the sync:

```
svnsync init file:///c:/backuprepo https://url/of/your/repository
```

Or on Unix:

```
svnsync init file:///Volumes/volumelabel/backuprepo https://url/of/your/repository
```

After that, you can simply run

```
svnsync sync file:///c:/backuprepo
```

once a day or so, and you'll get only those changes which are not yet in your backup repository. The first time it will take a while, but after you've synchronized your backup repository with the real one, it will only take a few seconds to sync it because only those revisions that are new need to be synched.

Comment: I'd vote this up twice, if I could. Unlike the other answers posted here, this one is actually correct. rsync: isn't certain to capture the repository in a consistent state. bdb repositories aren't binary-compatible across platforms. svnadmin dump requires access to the server.

Comment: If you're running on an UNIX like server, don't forget to give your hook execution rights or it's considered failed: `chmod a+x pre-revprop-change`

Comment: Also on UNIX like servers, don't forget to add `#!/bin/sh` to the top of `pre-revprop-change`.

Comment: `svnsync: Path 'file:///Volumes/volumelabel/backuprepo' is not a URL`

Comment: If you're still getting *svnsync: E165001: Revprop change blocked by pre-revprop-change hook (exit code 255) with no output.*, it's probably missing execution rights: `chmod +x ./backuprepo/hooks/pre-revprop-change`

Answer (score 24):

As of subversion 1.7, you can also use the new command [`svnrdump`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnrdump.c.dump.html). From the docs:

> Dump—that is, generate a repository dump stream of—revisions of the repository item located at SOURCE_URL, printing the information to standard output.

Usage would be:

```
svnrdump dump http://example.com/repos/ > repos.dump
```

This creates a "dump file" of the repository in `repos.dump`. This is a complete backup of your repository data including history, but is not directly readable by a subversion client. If you need to restore this data, use the standard `svnadmin` tools:

```
svnadmin create c:\backup-repos
svnadmin load c:\backup-repos < repos.dump
```

Haven't done any testing, but this might end up being slower than `svnsync`. `svnrdump` will do a complete dump of the repository everytime, where I'm assuming `synsync` will only import changes in the repository since the last time it was run. You will have a single file containing your entire repository though, which may or may not be easier to manage.

Note that you may want to pipe the output of `svnrdump` through `gzip` or similar program to possibly significantly reduce the size of the outputted file.

Comment: Soooo much faster. This is perfect.

Answer (score 12):

create your local repository

`svnadmin create /Users/jsmith/repo`

create an empty pre-revprop-change hook script

`echo '#!/bin/bash' > /Users/jsmith/repo/hooks/pre-revprop-change`

make the pre-revprop-change hook script executable

`chmod +x /Users/jsmith/backup/hooks/pre-revprop-change`

initialize svnsync

`svnsync init file:////Users/jsmith/repo https://www.smith.com/repo`

synchronize repos

`svnsync sync file:////Users/jsmith/repo`

Answer (score 7):

[rsync](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/) (or [DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp) which is a Windows UI on top of it) would be a good choice to incrementally copy the complete repository at the filesystem level.

You can also use [svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svnsync) to copy new revisions directly from one SVN server to another.

Comment: The issue with using rsync though is if you are copying the repository while someone is making a change the copy could become corrupted. svnsync is much safer than just copying the repository.

Comment: Yes svnsync would be the preferred solution. It's only supported on SVN server since I think version 1.6, but that seems to be widely deployed now.

Comment: Although your answer may be ok, next to the locking problem mentioned by @darrickc there is another disadvantage: it also requires a filesystem-level access to the svn repo. In most cases it isn't given, only an svn:// or http(s):// url.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a script on a remote server which dumps the repository, then copies it to your local computer (or leaves it in a predefined location for your local computer to copy)

You can either sync the backup directories with [rsync](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/) or [scp](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/).

The script can be run with "Scheduled Tasks" and can produce uniquely named backup files, which will later by synced in the above mentioned way by your local computer. (and then possibly deleted)

Answer (score 2):

EFraim mentioned rsync while I wrote this so that's covered.

If you don't want to work with that, the Subversion Book offers the `svnadmin dump --incremental` option explained here:

- [**Repository Maintenance**](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05s03.html) (scroll down the page to the "backup" section)
- [**Migrating a repository**](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05s03.html#svn-ch-5-sect-3.5) has examples on `svnadmin dump --incremental`

However, to do this successfully, you have to juggle with revision numbers - rsync'ing the raw repository data directories will be easier.

The hard part will probably be setting up rsync so your local and remote machine can communicate securely (i.e. set up an SSH service on the 2003 server). DeltaCopy that Wim mentions is very interesting and would be my first shot; for command line operation only, here is a howto on [**how to get Rsync running as a service on Windows 2003**](http://www.brentnorris.net/rsyncntdoc.html).

Answer (score 1):

I would use either `svnsync` or `svnadmin hotcopy` as both of these techniques are guaranteed to copy valid data from the repository, even if a transaction is in progress. Other file synchronisation techniques may not be as reliable, depending upon the repository format.

Answer (score 0):

In Mac OS X 10.10, the `svnrdump` command is located here:

- `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/svnrdump`

You can then use the answer above by joesdiner.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Stefans answer, here are some windows batch scripts to help automate the process a little.

**svn-backup-init.bat**

```
@echo off
set /P directory="Local Directory: "
set /P URL="Svn URL: "

echo "Running SVN backup";

@echo on
svnadmin create %directory%
echo exit 0 > %directory%\hooks\pre-revprop-change.bat
svnsync init file:///%directory% %URL%
svnsync sync file:///%directory%**strong text**
```

This script will create the svn repo, and check it out and do a sync immediately. When you run the script just enter the directory to put the repo locally and the URL of the server to use.

**svn-backup-run.bat**

```
for /d %%i in (%~dp0*) do ( svnsync sync file:///%%i )
```

This will loop through each directory and run the svnsync command. If you have multiple repos, check them out into the same folder. This can then easily be added as a Task in windows to update all your repos at once.

**Folder Structure**

I use a folder structure as such:

```
.
├── svn-backups
|   ├── repo-1
|   ├── repo-2
|   ├── repo-3
|   ├── svn-backup-init.bat
|   └── svn-backup-run.bat
```