# Why is git svn fetch so slow?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'm trying to `git svn fetch` my repo to perform a `git rebase -i`  I'm performing the fetch locally why is it so slow?  Should it really take so much time to create 1000 revisions?  It seems like the process just "falls a sleep" on a file then suddenly there is a flurry of activity.

Comment: SVN by nature is slow. Remember Git needs the *entire* history locally, so it checks out *every* revision from SVN. SVN doesn't pull the entire repository down, just a specific revision.

Comment: Even though I'm not doing any remote operations?

Comment: What do you mean you're "performing the fetch locally" -- `git svn fetch` fetches revisions from the svn repository. Even if you've already fetched all the revisions, it checks the svn repository to see whether it has them all or not.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear.  What I mean is I'm surprised that performing all the operations using git on the same server where svn is running, and copying from c:\svn\subversion to c:\git\subversion is so slow.  Your saying that's just the nature of the beast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

git svn fetch ( and clone) have to do the heavy lifting and create the entire repository, talking to svn and creating the git repository on your local machine. You may do it on the same server where the svn server is ( which is what I think you meant by locally), but still the git svn client has to process a lots of revisions, processing them one-by-one and creating the repo. 1000 revisions is a lot, it might take a while. Be patient and let it do its job. When you work on the repo, make sure you fetch / rebase often.

Comment: 2 days, 2 restarted servers, 1 hard drive ran out of space, 24 hours later and I finally got it to complete.

Comment: 28000 revisions is even more ;(

Comment: Nope, there is no heavy lifting...  This is just a performance bug in the windows port of 'git svn'.

Answer (score 26):

This seems to be a problem of the windows port of 'git svn'. Or more specifically one of the perl libraries of 'git svn' on windows/cygwin.

cloning a 12MB 75 revision svn repo

```
  linux: 45 seconds
  windows (cygwin): 25 minutes
```

Comment: 2 years and 8 months later: the problem persists. It may have gotten a tiny bit better. This morning, cloning the same repository took 44 seconds on linux, and (on average) 12 minutes on various windows machines.

Comment: And this of course (I think) was the question, not sure why the accepted answer doesn't say anything about this. Isn't there any way to fix this? For the record I'm running (the linux console emulator) Cmdr and that has the same problem.

Comment: 2019 year, `git-scm`, `git version 2.22.0.windows.1`, `git svn fetch` the same shite slow of slowness.

Comment: 2022, git version 2.35.1.windows.2

Comment: 2024, git ver 2.42.0.windows.2; git svn fetch, also git svn show-ignore, still super super slow do to no batching.

Comment: Um, git itself is open source right? Though I see it isn't on github except for a mirror. That is unfortunate as github is what makes so many open source libraries actually easy to contribute to (and for people to even see the internal development going on). Nevertheless, maybe someone should/could contribute an improvement to this? Anyone know if that's practical to do in reality?

Answer (score 6):

After going through the same thing, I found it's quite a bit faster on linux than it is with cygwin on windows.  I'd give that a try.

Comment: Yes Cygwin is typically [slower](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6811435/266535). But isn't there a git built for Windows?

Comment: Specifically, it was perl that was slow, I don't know if msysgit suffers from the same thing.

Comment: Just tried running the same `git svn clone` command (cloning from a local svn repo) from windows and (a VM running) linux. Git versions: Win: 1.8.3.msysgit.0, Linux: 1.8.3.2. Linux is *BLAZING* compared to Windows! I didn't expect that.

Comment: Thanks. Firing up a linux VM with VirtualBox, doing the `git svn clone` there, then cloning that into cygwin (and bringing over the git-svn config) just saved me a few hours.

Comment: Look at the processes behind the scenes with Process Explorer, it spawns a `pearl.exe` repeatedly to do the job.

Answer (score 3):

This problem still persists for Windows: pulling/fetching hangs, and nothing happens.

As an addition to all previous answers, I could suggest using of [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) on your Windows machine. You'll be pleasantly surprised by the speed with which the `fetch` will take place. It works like a charm.